# How can I get the number of groups with only 1 member?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying

```
select count(*)
  from groups
  left join members on groups.id=members.group_id
 group by groups.id
having count(members.id)=1
```

but it just gives me a bunch of 1s. how can I get the row count?

Comment: Please make an effort to lay your code out in a readable fashion in future.

Comment: @marcelo: it was readable. it wasn't that long. if you think that's bad, you should see how long most of the other lines of code are here.

Comment: @Mark: could you try my effort is working or not?

Comment: @Shakti: no, that won't work. your not counting the right thing, and that won't return a singular number either.

Comment: @Mark: I don't care what disasters you've seen here or elsewhere. The code was poorly formatted, end of story. When you are the one asking the question, the onus is on you to make it as easy as practicable for others to help you. You aren't doing yourself any favours by making excuses for it.

Comment: @Marcelo: Chill. I didn't format it better because I didn't realize it was poor. I can't fix something that I don't perceive as broken. You're arguing a matter of preference. Would you freak out if I didn't put my curly braces on a separate line? or the same line? Sheesh. I'll keep in mind that you like your SQL on separate lines for next time, OK?

Comment: I personally don't like the way you've indented it. Why is the FROM indented? And the HAVING isn't? Your style doesn't even make sense to me. If I were to put it on different lines, I'd put SELECT,FROM,GROUP BY, and HAVING all on the same line, and I'd indent the LEFT JOIN because it's part of the FROM clause (choosing tables)

Comment: @Mark - You don't see why it is of benefit to have all the query visible at any one time as opposed to having to horizontally scroll backwards and forwards?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, yes, fine, fine. I admit it! I was at work, and I was being lazy. I apologize =(

Comment: @Mark: As much as you think I'm being an uptight PITA, I am actually trying to help you. The trick is to not take yourself too seriously, and appreciate that good advice sometimes tastes like medicine. I get fed medicine all the time on SO, but that's fine, because it's my mistakes from which I learn the most.

Comment: @Marcelo: It's all good. I understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the results of your query by embedding it as a sub-query.

As a side note, an inner join would be more appropriate than an outer join for your query. In fact, you only need the join if there are invalid group_id values in the members table.

With inner join:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select groups.id
  from groups 
  inner join members on groups.id=members.group_id
  group by groups.id
  having count(members.id)=1
) as sub
```

Without join (assuming no orphans):

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select group_id
  from members
  group_id
  having count(*) = 1
) as sub
```

Comment: oh yeah...guess i wouldn't need the join. this data is pretty poor though,...all kinds of missing things.

Answer (score 1):

Your asking for the count of each group having 1 member. So a bunch of ones is correct. You might try using a subquery like...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  select count(*)
    from groups
    left join members on groups.id=members.group_id
   group by groups.id
  having count(members.id)=1
)
```

Comment: yes, the result was correct, my logic was flawed :) this works. but mysql complains "Every derived table must have its own alias". adding "AS T" at the end works, but I don't know MySQL makes that necessary.

Comment: Ahh...didn't realize MySQL had that requirement. Feel free to edit the answer to reflect the actual query that worked for you.

Comment: also, using a `select 1` instead of `select count(*)` on the inner statement would be faster, no?